# Scheduling - First or Next Available Appointment with MySQL

Tags: mysql, data-modeling

I am looking for first available appointment with all doctors or next available appointment based on the given date.

**Tables:-**

1. doctor_working_hours --> This is to store doctors availability for all days in a week.
2. doctor_working_exception --> This is to store doctors exceptions like lunch hours or so for all days in a week.
3. appointment --> This is to stored the booked appointments.

**Table:-** doctor_working_hours

| doctor_id | working_day | st_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 8:00 | 17:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 8:00 | 17:00 |
| 1 | 3 | 8:00 | 15:00 |
| 1 | 4 | 9:00 | 16:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 8:00 | 17:00 |
| 2 | 5 | 8:00 | 17:00 |
| 3 | 2 | 8:00 | 15:00 |
| 4 | 4 | 9:00 | 16:00 |

Here, working_day 1 for Sunday and 2 for Monday, ...

**Table:-** doctor_working_exception

| doctor_id | working_day | st_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 12:00 | 13:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 12:00 | 13:00 |
| 1 | 3 | 13:00 | 14:00 |
| 1 | 4 | 13:00 | 14:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 12:00 | 13:00 |
| 2 | 5 | 12:00 | 13:00 |
| 3 | 2 | 12:00 | 13:00 |
| 4 | 4 | 12:00 | 13:00 |

**Appointment:-**

| appt_id | doctor_id | st_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-10-08 09:30 | 2021-10-08 09:45 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-10-08 10:30 | 2021-10-08 11:00 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-10-09 09:30 | 2021-10-08 09:45 |
| 4 | 2 | 2021-10-08 09:30 | 2021-10-08 09:45 |
| 5 | 2 | 2021-10-09 09:30 | 2021-10-08 09:45 |
| 6 | 3 | 2021-10-08 09:30 | 2021-10-08 09:45 |
| 7 | 4 | 2021-10-08 09:30 | 2021-10-08 09:45 |

1. My requirement is to find the first available appoint with each doctor for the given duration. The duration could be 15 mins or 30 mins or 45 mins based on the Appointment type.
2. It has to return the next available appointment with a given doctor after the given date.
3. Return all free slots by given duration with a given doctor b/w the given time period.

> Fiddle Link:- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b48bf8/3

1. Query to get st_time and end_time by adding duration to st_time

> SELECT appt_id, st_time, ADDTIME(st_time, duration * 100) AS end_time
> from apptointment;
> **--> Returns null for appt_id 3. Unable to add 60
> mins to start time.**

2. Query to get available slots

> SELECT Available_from, Available_to
> FROM ( SELECT @lasttime_to AS Available_from,
> st_time AS Available_to,
> @lasttime_to := end_time
> FROM ( SELECT st_time, ADDTIME(st_time, duration * 100) AS end_time
> FROM apptointment
> WHERE doctor_id = 1
> AND st_time >= '2021-09-16 09:00'
> AND st_time < '2021-09-16 17:00'
> ORDER BY st_time ) e
> JOIN ( SELECT @lasttime_to := NULL ) init ) x
> WHERE Available_to >= DATE_ADD(Available_from, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);

This query returns nothing. What I need is to return all available slots by interval.

3. Query to get Available slot b/w given time for a particular doctor.

I am not sure, How to combine the doctor_working_hours and doctor_working_exception

**Note:-**

Currently, This logic has been implemented in Java and would like to move to MySQL engine.

Answer (score 1):

In order to explain it better I will start by setting the input variables as you have in your example:

```
SET @input_doctor_id = 1;
SET @input_date = '2021-09-16';
SET @input_duration = 15;
```

Your fiddle was helpful and I used your sample data (there is a small typo  *apptointment* and I kept it).

In order to see the appointments of the doctor for specified date run this query:

```
SELECT *, DATE_ADD(st_time, INTERVAL duration MINUTE) AS end_date
FROM apptointment
WHERE doctor_id = @input_doctor_id
    AND st_time > @input_date 
    AND st_time < DATE_ADD(@input_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY st_time
;
```

The output is:

| appt_id | doctor_id | st_time | duration | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-09-16 08:00:00 | 15 | 2021-09-16 08:15:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-09-16 08:30:00 | 45 | 2021-09-16 09:15:00 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-09-16 14:00:00 | 60 | 2021-09-16 15:00:00 |
| 4 | 1 | 2021-09-16 16:00:00 | 15 | 2021-09-16 16:15:00 |

Let's treat the exception hours and start working time and end working time as appointments and do a UNION of them:

```
-- real appointments
SELECT doctor_id
    , st_time
    , DATE_ADD(st_time, INTERVAL duration MINUTE) AS end_time 
FROM apptointment
WHERE doctor_id = @input_doctor_id
    AND st_time >= @input_date 
    AND st_time < DATE_ADD(@input_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
UNION
-- working start hour as appointment only if there is no appointment with same starting hour
SELECT wh.doctor_id
    , TIMESTAMP(@input_date, wh.st_time) AS st_time
    , TIMESTAMP(@input_date, wh.st_time) AS end_time
FROM doctor_working_hours AS wh
LEFT JOIN apptointment AS a ON a.doctor_id = wh.doctor_id AND a.st_time = TIMESTAMP(@input_date, wh.st_time)
WHERE wh.doctor_id = @input_doctor_id
    AND wh.working_day = DAYOFWEEK(@input_date)
    AND a.appt_id IS NULL
UNION
-- working end hour as appointment
SELECT doctor_id
    , TIMESTAMP(@input_date, end_time) AS st_time
    , TIMESTAMP(@input_date, end_time) AS end_time
FROM doctor_working_hours
WHERE doctor_id = @input_doctor_id
    AND working_day = DAYOFWEEK(@input_date)
UNION
-- exception interval as appointment
SELECT doctor_id
    , TIMESTAMP(@input_date, st_time) AS st_time
    , TIMESTAMP(@input_date, end_time) AS end_time
FROM doctor_working_exception
WHERE doctor_id = @input_doctor_id
    AND working_day = DAYOFWEEK(@input_date)
ORDER BY st_time
;
```

The output will be:

| doctor_id | st_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-16 08:00:00 | 2021-09-16 08:15:00 |
| 1 | 2021-09-16 08:30:00 | 2021-09-16 09:15:00 |
| 1 | 2021-09-16 12:00:00 | 2021-09-16 13:00:00 |
| 1 | 2021-09-16 14:00:00 | 2021-09-16 15:00:00 |
| 1 | 2021-09-16 16:00:00 | 2021-09-16 16:15:00 |
| 1 | 2021-09-16 17:00:00 | 2021-09-16 17:00:00 |

Now for each of these appointments we need to find the next appointment in order to compute the difference between them, and to remove those with difference smaller than the set duration (15, 30 or 45 minutes). Prepare for a long query:

```
SELECT a1.end_time AS available_st_time
    , MIN(a2.st_time) AS available_end_time
    , TIMEDIFF(MIN(a2.st_time), a1.end_time) AS available_duration
FROM (
    -- real appoitments
    SELECT doctor_id
        , st_time
        , DATE_ADD(st_time, INTERVAL duration MINUTE) AS end_time 
    FROM apptointment
    WHERE doctor_id = @input_doctor_id
        AND st_time >= @input_date 
        AND st_time < DATE_ADD(@input_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    UNION
    -- working start hour as appoitment only if there no appoitment at starting our
    SELECT wh.doctor_id
        , TIMESTAMP(@input_date, wh.st_time) AS st_time
        , TIMESTAMP(@input_date, wh.st_time) AS end_time
    FROM doctor_working_hours AS wh
    LEFT JOIN apptointment AS a ON a.doctor_id = wh.doctor_id AND a.st_time = TIMESTAMP(@input_date, wh.st_time)
    WHERE wh.doctor_id = @input_doctor_id
        AND wh.working_day = DAYOFWEEK(@input_date)
        AND a.appt_id IS NULL
    UNION
    -- working end hour as appoitment
    SELECT doctor_id
        , TIMESTAMP(@input_date, end_time) AS st_time
        , TIMESTAMP(@input_date, end_time) AS end_time
    FROM doctor_working_hours
    WHERE doctor_id = @input_doctor_id
        AND working_day = DAYOFWEEK(@input_date)
    UNION
    -- exception interval as appoitment
    SELECT doctor_id
        , TIMESTAMP(@input_date, st_time) AS st_time
        , TIMESTAMP(@input_date, end_time) AS end_time
    FROM doctor_working_exception
    WHERE doctor_id = @input_doctor_id
        AND working_day = DAYOFWEEK(@input_date)
) AS a1
LEFT JOIN (
    -- real appoitments
    SELECT doctor_id
        , st_time
        , DATE_ADD(st_time, INTERVAL duration MINUTE) AS end_time 
    FROM apptointment
    WHERE doctor_id = @input_doctor_id
        AND st_time >= @input_date 
        AND st_time < DATE_ADD(@input_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    UNION
    -- working start hour as appoitment only if there no appoitment at starting our
    SELECT wh.doctor_id
        , TIMESTAMP(@input_date, wh.st_time) AS st_time
        , TIMESTAMP(@input_date, wh.st_time) AS end_time
    FROM doctor_working_hours AS wh
    LEFT JOIN apptointment AS a ON a.doctor_id = wh.doctor_id AND a.st_time = TIMESTAMP(@input_date, wh.st_time)
    WHERE wh.doctor_id = @input_doctor_id
        AND wh.working_day = DAYOFWEEK(@input_date)
        AND a.appt_id IS NULL
    UNION
    -- working end hour as appoitment
    SELECT doctor_id
        , TIMESTAMP(@input_date, end_time) AS st_time
        , TIMESTAMP(@input_date, end_time) AS end_time
    FROM doctor_working_hours
    WHERE doctor_id = @input_doctor_id
        AND working_day = DAYOFWEEK(@input_date)
    UNION
    -- exception interval as appoitment
    SELECT doctor_id
        , TIMESTAMP(@input_date, st_time) AS st_time
        , TIMESTAMP(@input_date, end_time) AS end_time
    FROM doctor_working_exception
    WHERE doctor_id = @input_doctor_id
        AND working_day = DAYOFWEEK(@input_date)
) AS a2 ON a1.st_time < a2.st_time
GROUP BY a1.st_time, a1.end_time
HAVING available_duration >= SEC_TO_TIME(@input_duration * 60)
;
```

The output for this will be:

| available_st_time | available_end_time | available_duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-16 08:15:00 | 2021-09-16 08:30:00 | 00:15:00 |
| 2021-09-16 09:15:00 | 2021-09-16 12:00:00 | 02:45:00 |
| 2021-09-16 13:00:00 | 2021-09-16 14:00:00 | 01:00:00 |
| 2021-09-16 15:00:00 | 2021-09-16 16:00:00 | 01:00:00 |
| 2021-09-16 16:15:00 | 2021-09-16 17:00:00 | 00:45:00 |

For the date '2021-09-23' when there are no appointments the output will be:

| available_st_time | available_end_time | available_duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-23 08:00:00 | 2021-09-23 12:00:00 | 04:00:00 |
| 2021-09-23 13:00:00 | 2021-09-23 17:00:00 | 04:00:00 |

For dates which are out of doctor's working days the output will be empty.

Comment: Awesome !!! It works as expected for the given date. The first query is simple and the 2nd query is a big query. I am thinking to go with the first query and handle some stuff in java layer as the 2nd query might put lots of load on the SQL engine. I was trying to leverage this to multiple days ( b/w two dates ) and for multiple doctors. Goal is to find the Next available appointment with all the doctor for the given duration?